# Can you include CSS Backdrop-Filters in print?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I'm working on a page that has a single layer acting as a filter for the content beneath it.

```css
#filter {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div id='filter'></div>
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

The page is intended to be printed from the browser, but the backdrop filter isn't applied(although other fixed elements are shown correctly). Is there a way to include the backdrop filter in print? Tested on Chrome and Safari.

[For more information on Backdrop-filter effects](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit)

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue here. When we outputs html to pdf files using `chrome --headless` or `puppeteer`, backdrop filter blur effects don't appear

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS Backdrop-Filters are not currently supported for printing. Backdrop-Filters are a type of visual effect that can be applied to an element, such as blur or color shifting. However, these effects are not directly related to the content of the element and are not typically relevant to the printed version of a document.

When a web page is printed, the browser generates a print layout that is optimized for printing on paper. This layout is usually simplified and stripped of non-essential elements, such as background images and visual effects. While some styles can be applied to the printed version of a document using print-specific styles, CSS Backdrop-Filters are not currently supported.

Therefore, if you want to apply visual effects to the printed version of your document, you will need to use alternative techniques, such as creating separate print-specific styles that achieve the desired effect or using a print-specific stylesheet to apply styles only when the document is printed.